# Unstacking values into different rows in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a DataFrame (below). I am interested in unstacking the `from` and `to` columns.

[image]

I need to unstack `from` and `to` columns into multiple rows for each  different year between `from` and `to`. For example, the first row will produce something like this

[image]

I tried everything from [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to [`pd.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a column of array-like objects with all of the years between 'from' and 'to' then  [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) on that column. It won't be the most efficient solution, but it's simple.

**Sample Data**

```
   a  b  c  d  e  from    to
0  2  9  1  7  3  1940  1945
1  5  6  2  6  1  1950  1951
```

**Code**

```
df['year'] = [np.arange(f,t+1) for f,t in zip(df['from'], df['to'])]
df = df.explode('year')
```

---

```
   a  b  c  d  e  from    to  year
0  2  9  1  7  3  1940  1945  1940
0  2  9  1  7  3  1940  1945  1941
0  2  9  1  7  3  1940  1945  1942
0  2  9  1  7  3  1940  1945  1943
0  2  9  1  7  3  1940  1945  1944
0  2  9  1  7  3  1940  1945  1945
1  5  6  2  6  1  1950  1951  1950
1  5  6  2  6  1  1950  1951  1951
```

Comment: Thank you. Never heard of this `pd.explode()` method. It worked.